# Alternative to Resurrectio

Tags: web-scraping, phantomjs, casperjs

For those of you that have tried using [Resurrectio](https://github.com/ebrehault/resurrectio) have probably noticed that it hardly works. Has anybody forked this project or can suggest an alternative to recording browser behavior and exporting it as casper.js? Or something similar to this?

I am using [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) version `1.9.8` and [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) version `1.1.0-beta3`. I am open to using different version of Phantom and Casper if I have to.

If anyone can suggest a different tool (javascript based) for web scraping, that would be great too.

Thanks in advance!